# Whats wrong, my app always stuck at AwesomeProject welcome page

Tags: react-native

So i am stuck in there. I just want to add a  but it never renders it.
It renders the "Registered project page".

index.ios.js

```
import native from './src';

native();
```

./src/index.js

```
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default function index() {
    class Root extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Text>
                    Welcome to React Native!
                </Text>
            );
        }
    }


     AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => Root);
}
```

[image: AwesomeProject]
So it all works great. I can even debug and see that the App component is called etc. But why i never get to render anything except that window ?

Comment: logs, logs, logs....

Comment: Curious.. why are you defining a class inside a function?

Comment: @Andreyco - Well, there is nothing in the logs....

Comment: @Andreyco So this is in the debugger-ui : `Console was cleared
RCTLog.js:45 Running application AwesomeProject ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
infoLog.js:17 Running application "AwesomeProject" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
YellowBox.js:71 Remote debugger is in a background tab which may cause apps to perform slowly. Fix this by foregrounding the tab (or opening it in a separate window).

Comment: In react-packager console : Loading dependency graph, done.
Bundling `index.ios.js`  100.0% (675/675), done.
Bundling `index.ios.js`  100.0% (408/408), done.
Bundling `index.ios.js`  100.0% (1/1), done.
Bundling `index.ios.js`  100.0% (1/1), done.
Bundling `index.ios.js`  100.0% (1/1), done.

Comment: @sooper Why not ? Notice that the project do get registered, based on the screenshot .. right ? maybe not .... ?!?!

Comment: So, what am i missing to debug react-native app ? Is there anything more we can add to understand whats going on ? Not sure i understand the workflow for development ...

Comment: Is it possible that the simulator is not showing my actual code ?

Comment: No, the screenshot is showing your `LaunchScreen.xib`, not your react native view.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and ran in ios and its working for me...